# Search multiple worksheets and copy all rows with a where column A is >0 to a specified worksheet

Tags: excel, rows, conditional-statements, worksheet

Greetings,

I've looked quite a bit for code to help me do this, and though I've found several pieces that hint around it, maybe it's my inexperience with vba, but I haven't been able to modify anything to work for me.  I have a workbook with several worksheets of quantities, parts, descriptions.  The quantity is in column a.  The first 3 rows of each workbook are a header.  I'm looking to have code in my "Summary" worksheet that searches all the other worksheets and compiles all the quantity, parts, and description information (columns a, b, and c) on the Summary sheet, so basically I end up with a list on the summary page of every item with a quantity greater than 0, starting on row 4.  Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch,
William

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to solve the problem while I see that eggplant_parm had already answered you.
By the way this is my solution, quite similar to his one.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy_info()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
With Sheets("Summary")
.Cells.Clear
.Range("A1") = "Quantity"
.Range("B1") = "Parts"
.Range("C1") = "Description"
.Range("D1") = "Sheet name"
.Range("A1:D1").Font.Bold = True
End With

j = 2

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name <> "Summary" Then
        lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 4 To lastRow
            If sh.Range("A" & i) > 0 Then
                sh.Range("a" & i & ":c" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & j)
                Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & j) = sh.Name
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next sh
Sheets("Summary").Columns("A:D").AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks to all for your help.  Makes it a lot easier to make sense of what is what when you have something that works to start with.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if I understand your setup correctly.

```
Sub GetParts()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim W As Worksheet, r As Single, i As Single
    i = 4
    For Each W In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If W.Name <> "Summary" Then
            For r = 4 To W.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                If W.Cells(r, 1) > 0 Then
                    Range(W.Cells(r, 1), W.Cells(r, 3)).Copy _
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Cells(i, 1)
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next r
        End If
    Next W
End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error '1004':    Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.   =/

Comment: @William Hmm, it works for me. Maybe try adding a worksheet reference to the range you're copying?
    W.Range(W.Cells(r,1),...

Answer (score 1):

it 's a little long but, i think that this approach will allow you to modify the code more easily
I hope it helps.

```
Public Sub main()

'Using PrintCollection,ReadCollection and FilterCollection

    PrintColl Ws:="Sheet3", _
                    coll:=FilterColl( _
                            coll:=ReadColl( _
                                WSs:=Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"), _
                                fRow:=4, _
                                lRow:=-1, _
                                fCol:=1, _
                                lCol:=2)), _
                    fRow:=1, _
                    fCol:=3
End Sub

'Function to determine if table(index) should be included in the result.

Function MyFilter(ByRef table As Variant, ByVal index As Integer) As Boolean
    If table(index, 1) > 0 Then
        MyFilter = True
    Else
        MyFilter = False
    End If
End Function

'Takes an array of worksheet names and 4 parameters that represent a range
'It asumes that Cols are adjacent and the data starts in the same row
'Pass a negative value to lRow to look down the first Col of every worksheet
'returns a Collection with WS names as key and arrays with the range values

Function ReadColl(ByRef WSs As Variant, _
                  ByVal fRow As Integer, ByVal lRow As Integer, _
                  ByVal fCol As Integer, ByVal lCol As Integer) As collection
    Dim coll As New collection
    Dim l As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(WSs, 1)
        If lRow < 0 Then
            l = LastNumber(WSs(i), fRow, fCol)
        Else
            l = lRow
        End If
        coll.Add ReadTbl(WSs(i), fRow, l, fCol, lCol), WSs(i)
    Next i
    Set ReadColl = coll
End Function

'Read the values in a WS into an array

Function ReadTbl(ByVal Ws As String, _
                 ByVal fRow As Integer, ByVal lRow As Integer, _
                 ByVal fCol As Integer, ByVal lCol As Integer) As Variant
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Ws).Select
 Range(Cells(fRow, fCol), Cells(lRow, lCol)).Select
 ReadTbl = Selection.Value
End Function

'Filter every table inside the collection supplied

Function FilterColl(ByRef coll As collection) As collection
    Dim filtered As New collection
    Dim table As Variant
    For Each table In coll
        filtered.Add (FilterTbl(table))
    Next table
    Set FilterColl = filtered
End Function

'Returns a new table composed by elements that make MyFilter true

Function FilterTbl(ByRef table As Variant) As Variant
    Dim filtered As New collection
    Dim elem() As Variant
    ReDim elem(1 To UBound(table, 2))
    For i = 1 To UBound(table, 1)
        If MyFilter(table, i) = True Then
            For j = 1 To UBound(table, 2)
                elem(j) = table(i, j)
            Next j
            filtered.Add elem, CStr(i)
        End If
    Next i
    FilterTbl = CollToTbl(filtered)
End Function

'Auxiliary function to solve array limitations in vba

Function CollToTbl(ByRef coll As collection) As Variant
    If coll.Count > 0 Then
        Dim ary() As Variant
        Dim item As Variant
        Dim nCols As Integer
        nCols = UBound(coll(1), 1)
        ReDim ary(1 To coll.Count, 1 To nCols)
        For i = 1 To coll.Count
            For j = 1 To nCols
                ary(i, j) = coll(i)(j)
            Next j
        Next i
        CollToTbl = ary
    End If
End Function

'Takes Ws, a collection, and the first position where the result is expected

Sub PrintColl(ByVal Ws As String, ByRef coll As collection, _
              ByVal fRow As Integer, ByVal fCol As Integer)
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = fRow
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Ws).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    For i = 1 To coll.Count
        PrintTbl Ws, coll(i), pos, fCol
        pos = pos + UBound(coll(i), 1)
    Next i
End Sub

'Same as before except it outputs an specific table

Sub PrintTbl(ByVal Ws As String, ByRef table As Variant, _
             ByVal fRow As Integer, ByVal fCol As Integer)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Ws).Select
    Range(Cells(fRow, fCol), _
           Cells(fRow + UBound(table, 1) - 1, UBound(table, 2))).Select
    Selection.Value = table
End Sub

'Iterates Col in the WS starting in fRow until IsNumber returns false

Function LastNumber(ByVal Ws As String, _
                    ByVal fRow As Integer, ByVal Col As Integer) As Integer
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Ws).Select
    While WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(fRow, Col).Value)
        fRow = fRow + 1
    Wend
    LastNumber = fRow - 1
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.  I ended up working some of your ideas in, like ClearContents.  Thanks to everyone for their help.